# scrape table where rows need to be associated with previous elements

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the table from this website:
https://www.oddsportal.com/moving-margins/

I need data inside the table #moving_margins_content_overall

I tried this code but some games contains many class="odd" and I don't know how to associate the class="odd" data with the class="dark" data

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import json
import csv
from selenium import webdriver

u = 'https://www.oddsportal.com/moving-margins/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(u)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")    
driver.implicitly_wait(60) # seconds
time.sleep(2)
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*")
source_code = elem.get_attribute("innerHTML")
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, 'html.parser')

for k in soup.select('#moving_margins_content_overall .table-main tbody tr'):
    sport = k.select_one('tr.dark th > a').get_text(strip=True) #sport
    country = soup.select_one('tr.dark th a:nth-child(3) span').get_text(strip=True) #country
    competition = soup.select_one('tr.dark th a:nth-child(5)').get_text(strip=True) #sport
```

Comment: I am not sure if it is mandatory for you to work with BS or not. If you can work with just python  selenium binding there are ways to do it.

Comment: no, using BS is not mandatory, any option is ok for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below code to store all the data in a list in which each row in the page is stored as list.

```
u = 'https://www.oddsportal.com/moving-margins/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(u)
#Use Explicit time wait for fast execution
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#moving_margins_content_overall")))
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
table_data =  driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='moving_margins_content_overall']//tr[@class='odd' or @class='dark']")
table =[]
# Creating a list of lists, where each list consist all data in each row either with class dark or odd
for data in table_data:
    row = []
    dark_row = data.find_elements_by_xpath((".//th//a"))
    for col in dark_row:
        row.append(col.text.replace("\n"," "))
    row.append(data.find_element_by_xpath(".//following-sibling::tr//th[@class='first2']").text)# Add data in first2 th
    odd_row = data.find_elements_by_xpath((".//following-sibling::tr[@class='odd']//td"))
    for col in odd_row:
        row.append(col.text.replace("\n", " "))
    row.append(odd_row[-1].find_element_by_xpath('.//a').get_attribute("title")) #Add bookmaker name
    table.append(row)
for t in table:
    print(t)
```

**Output**  As you can see for rugby union match there are two odds so list for that game is long.

[image]

Comment: yes, this is good, but how to store this on csv file ? I mean I cant figure out how to associate single list of odd (example ['Today 17:15', 'La Calzada W - Malaga W', '-3.50 3.50', '1.90', '1.80', ' ']) to it's dark list (example ['Handball', ' Spain', 'Copa de la Reina Women']) when there are more than one odd list per one dark list

Comment: great, thanks, 2 more things if you don't mind: 1/ there is another data in a tr without class come always before tr="odd" (contain th[@class="first2"]), we can add this data ? 2/ we can add the bookmaker name (the last data on tr="odd") ?

Comment: Yes , could be done with some tweak . I will certainly have a look. However if original issue is resolved you can accept the answer. :)

Comment: please help me add those data and I will accept the answer for sure, I already rated it as useful.. I created this question maybe can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63756743/create-csv-file-where-each-row-is-some-nested-lists-from-one-list

Comment: Please check now. I have added book maker name and data on first2. Thanks will have a look

Comment: NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//following-sibling::tr//th[@class='first2']"}

Comment: anyway, even the previous reply is not accurate, matches with more than one tr[@class="odd"] are not accurate, I will accept the reply because you invested time on it, but please reply on this new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63757622/scrape-table-where-rows-are-distributed-between-many-tr

Comment: Please copy complete code and run, i am running and getting same result as shared.

Comment: same: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//following-sibling::tr//th[@class='first2']"}